# ASP.NET Core, link html element value with c# variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an SQL Database that I can access and write into and read form through the website. I have HTML `<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>` element to handle user input "username", I have variable in the cshtml code `"string username = null"` and a button that when I press it I want to link the input element value to the string, so that I can later on send it to the Database, can I do that?

```
@page
@model BlindTest.Pages.RegisterModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Pages/_Layout.cshtml";
    string username = Request["username"];
}

@{ 
<h2>Register</h2>
<br />
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
<br />
<Button>Register</Button>
}
```

I'm kind of stuck because Request[""] returns "Only assignment, call, decrement and new object expression can be used as a statement"

Here is the DB connection:

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;
@using System.Configuration
@using System.Data.SqlClient;
@{
    var user = "username";
    var password = "password";
    var serverName = "rinyiau.database.windows.net";

    SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionString = new SqlConectionStringBuilder();
    connectionString.DataSource = servername;
    connectionString.InitialCatalog = "rinyiau.database";
    connectionString.Integratedsecurity = false;
    connectionString.UserId = user;
    connectionString.Password = password;
    connectionString.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString) !-- <Uppercase --!
    SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader reader;

    query.CommandText = Some SQL code + username;
    query.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    query.Connection = conn;

    conn.Open();

    reader = query.ExecuteReader()

    conn.Close()
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?? Please post your code if you face any problems

Comment: Please update your post and paste the code over there, not in comments.

Comment: @TodorYanev, please update your comment in question itself...as it is diificult to read

Comment: Your error is because of Request["username"], it needs to be assigned to a variable

Comment: Also please refer https://www.javatpoint.com/asp-net-button

Comment: Yea but how do I do that in c#, I can't directly target the html element?

Comment: You could fill the value of the HTML input from your C# variable during rendering (on the server side) using Razor syntax: `<input type="text" name="username" value="@username"/>`. If you want to fill it on the client side (after user clicks the button), you have to use Javascript.

Comment: But thee MVC way would be to set the value of `Username` in the `RegisterModel` in the GET action of the controller, then render this property (including its current value) with `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Username)`.

Comment: Do you know how can I make it with JavaScript?